# How to store split sentences from a file in tokens (ArrayIndexBoundException error at 0) java?

Tags: java, split

I'm a newbie to Java and I'm reading sentences from a file called `a2b.txt` and this file contains sentences that goes like this.

`Read in the lines of text, process them into words, and store them
into an array (or, optionally, an ArrayList) of objects of your Sentence class.
Each Sentence object should start out empty, and have words added to it as they
are received from the file. Your Sentence class must contain at least the
following. If you are storing the sentences in an array, you can assume that the
text file contains at most 1000 sentences. Once you have read in the contents of
the file, process it in the following way!`

First, I splitted the file with the delimiters `.!` and I wanted to read each sentence into various objects when I got an arrayIndexBoundException error. 
This is my code.

```
BufferedReader input;
    String text;
    String[] words;
    String sentence1,sentence2, sentence3,sentence4,sentence5;

    sentence[] sentences = new sentence[1000];
    int size = 0;

    try{
        input= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a2b.txt"));

        text =input.readLine();
        while (text!=null){
            words = text.split(".|!");

            sentence1 = words[0].trim();
            sentence2 = words[1].trim();
            sentence3 = words[2].trim();
            sentence4 = words[3].trim();
            sentence5 = words[4].trim();

            sentences[size] = new sentence(sentence1);

            //for(int x =0; x< words.length;x++){
                //System.out.println(words[x]);

            //}
            text =input.readLine();
        }
        input.close();

    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        System.out.println(sentences[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an arrayIndexBountException at 0. I want my sentences to print out line by line after every `.!' .Any help on how to get through would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line is generating this error?

Comment: it seems to be starting at `sentence1 = words[0].trim();` @user2085282

Comment: I suggest you split the lines with `\\s+` (which is one or more white-space).

Comment: If that line is generating an `ArrayIndexBountException`, that would indicate that `words` contains fewer items than you are attempting to access. In this case, this would indicate that `words` contains no elements. That line and the ones like it can be dangerous, as you have no guarantee that `words` will have as many elements as you think.

Comment: this was supposed to be inside words first position and I splitted it to store them  `Read in the lines of text, process them into words, and store them
into an array (or, optionally, an ArrayList) of objects of your Sentence class.`  how is it possible that I have made words contain nothing? @user2085282

Comment: I am splitting the line based on `.!` which indicates the end of each sentences. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Consider that `String.split` uses a regular expression, where `.` means "any character at all". Additionally, it may be helpful to run your code in a debugger, and see what the value of `text` is when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Attaching the full stack trace would help.

Comment: Another potential wrinkle...How many lines (turn off word-wrapping in your editor) are there in `a2b.txt`?

Comment: Thanks I used another method to solve my problem. @user2085282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using ArrayList instead with the scanner class.

```
    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    //int size =0;


    try{

        File file = new File("a2b.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[.?!]");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            EachSentence = scanner.next();
            EachSentence = EachSentence.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", " ");
            EachSentence = EachSentence.trim();
            sentences.add(EachSentence);
        }
        scanner.close();

    }catch (IOException ex){ 
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

This printed the lines as I expected.

```
Read in the lines of text, process them into words, and store them into an array (or, optionally, an ArrayList) of objects of your Sentence class.

Each Sentence object should start out empty, and have words added to it as they are received from the file.

Your Sentence class must contain at least the following.

If you are storing the sentences in an array, you can assume that the text file contains at most 1000 sentences.

Once you have read in the contents of the file, process it in the following way.
```

using;

```
for(int i=0;i<sentences.size();i++){
      System.out.println("\n"+sentences.get(i)+".");
}
```